# Angular.js $watch on object....does not consider adding property a change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In Angular.js, I have this in my directive:

```
    scope.$watchCollection(function(){
          return StatusTrackerService.eventCollection
      }, function(){
          console.log("ssssssssssss");
          console.log(StatusTrackerService);
          console.log("ssssssssssss");
      });
```

---

In my service, I am feeding it `StatusTrackerService.eventCollection` and add a property to `eventCollection`:

```
    function runEventCheck(account, eventId) {
        url = urlBuilder(account, eventId);

        eventCollection[referenceVipLabel.vipLabel] = new NewStatusEvent(account, eventId, url);
    }
    return { runEventCheck: runEventCheck,
             eventCollection: eventCollection,
             referenceVipLabel: referenceVipLabel
    };
});
```

When I add a property to `eventCollection`, `$watch` does not detect a change. It seems to me adding a property to object `eventCollection` would change the object. Why isn't `$watch` detecting this change? I don't really want to use `$watchCollection` because then it detects any changes to `StatusTrackerService`.

Comment: `eventCollection` is `StatusTrackerService.eventCollection` right?

Comment: yes, eventCollection is StatusTrackerService.eventCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a deepwatch on the property. You can do it by setting the third argument [for `object equality`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on the watch.

```
 scope.$watch(function(){
      return StatusTrackerService.eventCollection; 
  }, function(v){
       console.log(v);
   }, true); //<-- Here
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDJZkb?p=preview)